Requery works on Button Click but not on TextBox Change
I have a main form containing a subform called "SF_Liste_Patients", the source object of the subform is a query, filtering on a criteria (TextBox called "entree_recherche_nom").
Query :
SELECT Patients.num_dossier, Patients.nom, Patients.nom_naissance, Patients.prenom, Patients.date_naissance FROM Patients WHERE Patients.nom Like \[entree_recherche_nom\] & "\*";

I have a search button on the main form:
Private Sub btn_rechercher_Click()
    Me.SF_Liste_Patients.Requery
End Sub

which works like a charm.
I want the requery to happen at every stroke on search criteria, so I tried this :
Private Sub entree_recherche_nom_Change()
    Me.SF_Liste_Patients.Requery
    MsgBox "change"
End Sub

The msgbox displays on every stroke, which means the event triggers every time, but in this case, the subform doesn't update
Precision : I opened the query and it doesn't show the result I want
Why do these two controls act a different way ?
Tell me if you need any precision that could help you find the problem, thank you.

This is because the textbox isn't updated, only changed.
You could update a textbox, FilterBox, and then use this to filter.
Property Text holds the current entry:
Private Sub entree_recherche_nom_Change()

    ' Set filter value.
    Me!FilterBox.Value = Me!entree_recherche_nom.Text
    ' Apply filter.
    Me!SF_Liste_Patients.Requery

    MsgBox "change"

End Sub

Adjust SQL:
SELECT Patients.num_dossier, Patients.nom, Patients.nom_naissance, Patients.prenom, Patients.date_naissance FROM Patients WHERE Patients.nom Like [FilterBox] & "*";

